# Swift - Large title & searchBar

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, swift3, uisearchbar

I'm trying to use the LargeTitle and the searchBar in my tableViewController.

I would like to have a white navigationBar and non translucent.

I really don't find any way to do that.

My code, into the viewDidLoad():

```
if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
         self.navigationController?.navigationBar.prefersLargeTitles = true
}

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = true
let img = UIImage(named: "backgroundNav")
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
searchController.searchBar.searchBarStyle = .minimal
self.navigationItem.searchController = searchController
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.shadowImage = UIImage()
```

The problem here is that there is a blank on the status bar when the searchBar is active:

[image]

I would like something like that.
[image]

If I remove those lines, it's working, but with a translucent navigationBar:

```
let img = UIImage(named: "backgroundNav")
navigationController?.navigationBar.setBackgroundImage(img, for: .default)
```

If you have any idea about how I could do that, it would be really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the navigation controller and set it's `prefer large title` in the IB. That should work. Let me know if that helps.